# how to input date and text in same textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am seeking help to input date and specific text on same textbox

Example i have a textbox where i want from user to input licence expiry date or just right NA instead of selecting date.

i want to give provision to user either he selects date form date time picker or just write NA.

Here is my code which i try but with this code i only select date

Jquery code to avoid selecting future dates

```
 $("#Personal_Cnic_Driving_licence_No_Expiry").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function (selected) {

        }
```

HTML Code

```
 <input type = "text" autocomplete="off"   class = "form-control"  name="Personal_Cnic_Driving_licence_No_Expiry" id = "Personal_Cnic_Driving_licence_No_Expiry"   style = "color:  black;" value="<?php echo $data['Personal_Cnic_Driving_licence_No_Expiry'];?>"  data-toggle="tooltip" title="Please Select Date of Driving Licence # Expiry If Applicable"   placeholder="Please Select Date of Driving Licence # Expiry If Applicable" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"/>
```

Need your kind consideration

Comment: you can handle this on backend side. like if the user enters expiredate then Store that date and if he/she does not select any value means You have to store NA

Comment: Thanks prakash m but i want user to select date either input NA from front end because textbox property is required .

so form is not submitted if he leave empty textbox

Comment: If 'NA' as a text is allowed then any valid text is allowed unless you add a strong validation to it. I think you should rather make this field optional and only allow date as an entry. On the UI part, you can grey out the field instead with a short side note as 'NA'

Comment: Rather than allow the input to be empty (is it "empty" or did the user forget?) - add a checkbox next to the input which would disable the input if ticked.  Much clearer UI/UX.